# How to remove single quote in a single quoted string?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need to remove a single quote in a single quoted email address with Sed.

I have tried matching with

```
    ,'.*(?<=@)
```

it is always including ,'def',' in the regex.

For example

```
    aabc,123,'def','me.o'le@abc.com',123,abc
```

to

```
    aabc,123,'def','me.ole@abc.com',123,abc
```

How can I do the subsitution without touching the rest of the single quotes ?

Thanks

Comment: Will the string `aabc,123,'def','me.ole@abc.com',123,abc` always be in this format?

Comment: Change `.*` to `[^']*`

Comment: Why do you need to use a single quote string? Why not double quote? Can you use the &#39; Unicode character instead of and " ' ". Assuming this is JavaScript, can you use the replace() function? Can you please provide more information so we can help. I would put this in a comment, but I do not have 50 reputations yet. Sorry.

Comment: According to the tags, it's Bash.

Comment: BTW, `(?<=...)` (like all lookahead and lookbehind) is a PCRE extension, not present in BRE (POSIX Basic Regular Expressions) or ERE (POSIX Extended Regular Expressions); standard `sed` isn't guaranteed to support it at all.

Comment: Can commas appear within your quoted fields, e.g. `foo,'Smith, Bill',bar`?

Comment: Can the question be reformatted into Remove all single quotes except for those next to comma, or at the begin/end of the line?

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified enough information about the constraints on the format of the input string. The following `sed` command, however, works with the example string you provided and many similar ones. (To be precise: it will work with any lines where there is only one character to remove, which can appear at any position in the name part of the email address, and the single-quote-delimited email address is itself neither the first nor the last comma-separated field. If there are more then two email addresses to correct, it will operate on the first.)

It should give you an idea. The key is anchoring your match between `,'` and `',`.

```
sed -e "s/\(,'[^']*\)'\([^']*@[^']*',\)/\1\2/"
```

Comment: Very nice: Only tweak would be to make sure characters follow the apostrophes, e.g. `sed -e "s/\(,'[^'][^']*\)[']\([^'][^']*@[^'][^']*',\)/\1\2/"`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin As I wrote, OP didn’t specify enough information on the format of those lines. We don’t know how those spurious apostrophes creep in. I supposed them to appear at any position in the name part of the address, including the very beginning, but it’s just a guess. Are you sure they would appear only after at least one character? ...Hmmm I’d better edit my answer to clarify that...

Comment: Agreed, I wasn't detracting from what you provided, but thinking though what an e-mail address might be, it made sense that he may want to ensure that there were at least characters between the quotes (that's more a validation than an actual requirement for removal though)